# Can you run Sapper with NODE_ENV=test

Tags: sapper

I'm converting a project from Angular + Node.js server --> Sapper. In relation to e2e tests, there is something I can't understand; can I run Sapper with `NODE_ENV` env variable set to test? When I run `export NODE_ENV=test && sapper dev` the variable is *always* `dev`. How can I fix this?

My current work-around is to build the application, and then start it with `node __sapper__/build`, but this is not very nice when developing e2e tests.

Answer (score 1):

Sapper is an open-source project, so we can check how `NODE_ENV` is set: https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper.

When running `sapper dev`, the environmental variable `NODE_ENV` is set in `/src/api/dev.ts`

```
(/src/api/dev.ts)
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
```

where it's *hard-coded* to `development`.

The variable can be set to other values (including `testing`) in

```
(/src/cli.ts)
178. process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production';
```

so I surmise you would need `sapper prod` (or something similar, check it) to use this `NODE_ENV`.

You should also check it that doesn't beat the purpose of what you're trying to achieve, perhaps sticking to `sapper dev` is preferable to running in non-dev mode.

Comment: Beat the purpose? My objective is to run Sapper in a test environment?

Comment: I cannot find anything about `NODE_ENV = test` in the code, but a lot about `process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development/production'` where it toggles functionality (like more logging on development). Also, here is an article where potential bugs are discussed when defining new environments: https://nemisj.com/not-use-node_env-defining-environments/. I didn't say that a custom node_env would beat the purpose, but it was a question on what differences in functionality you would like to see between development and testing :)